Pointer lock doesn't work on Safari during fullscreen
I'm developing a fullscreen game, where I need to programmatically enable and disable the pointer lock to let the user click on UI elements without exiting fullscreen. This seems to work fine on Chrome and Firefox, but fails in Safari.
I managed to reproduce the problem using a minimal plain HTML example:
const elem = document.getElementById("elem");
elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement)
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  else
    elem.requestPointerLock();
});

document.addEventListener("pointerlockchange", (e) => {
  if (document.pointerLockElement)
    elem.innerText = "Pointer lock is now active";
  else
    elem.innerText = "Pointer lock is now inactive";
});
document.addEventListener("pointerlockerror", (e) => {
  elem.innerText = "Pointer lock has failed";
});

<div id="elem" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red;">
  This element will go fullscreen
</div>

The first click on the element should activate the fullscreen mode, the second one should lock the pointer. On Chrome and Firefox this works properly, and "Pointer lock is now active" is displayed. On Safari, "Pointer lock has failed" is displayed instead, and neither the event or the JS console show any reason why.
However, if you modify the code to first request the pointer lock, and only then switch to fullscreen mode, everything seems to work fine in all browsers:
elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  elem.requestPointerLock();
});
document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  elem.requestFullscreen();
});
// click the element to lock the cursor first, then press space to enter fullscreen

But this doesn't achieve what I'm trying to do for my use case, as if you then release the pointer lock, it can't be reacquired without exiting fullscreen.
I could not find any reference to what could be causing this behavior in the docs.

Ye that is not supported in Safari:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestPointerLock#browser_compatibility

@HelderSepulveda Only unadjustedMovement is not supported on Safari, there is no mention of capturing the pointer during fullscreen being unsupported.

That's a relatively new bug, already reported at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=272136 It seems to have gathered enough traction for it to be fixed soon enough. In the mean time I'm not sure there is an actual workaround apart from getting off the fullscreen every time you need to lock the pointer...

@Kaiido Thanks! I expected this to be a browser bug, but couldn't find any references to it, so this pretty much answers my question. I guess I just have to work with it for now. Feel free to add this as an actual answer so I can mark it as accepted.

You may self answer if you wish

As it turns out, this is a regression in latest versions of Safari, and worked fine in the past. The related browser bug report can be found here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=272136
As a temporary workaround, I modified my fullscreen code to fill the browser tab when running on Safari, instead of launching proper fullscreen mode. This is likely the best that I can do until the bug is fixed.
